# Trying to plugin Intuit payment gateway into ZenCart

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, zen-cart

I am in no way a programmer, but I am trying my best to to follow online instructions and additional instructions from Intuit, but I have followed everything up to a point and now do not know where to proceed from here.

I have already...

1: Created an account
2: Created an App ID
3: Created a connection Ticket...

But now I have come to the point where I don't know where to proceed with the Connection Ticket ID#

I would assume I plug it into ZenCart somewhere but I have been unable to locate any online articles that point me in the right direction. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you written any code, or added a ZenCart payment module into ZenCart that you downloaded somewhere?

ZenCart does not support Intuit Merchant Services out of the box.